# Joomla / Gantry Multi language website error 404

Tags: joomla

I found a lot of resource on the web talking about issue like mine but nothing worked for me.

I build a joomla 3.4.1 website, installed a rocket theme template (momentum) based on Gantry.

I created 3 categories, 1 for each language. I created the pages. Both pages and categories are correctly set for the good language.

I left a main menu for all language, with a module, deactivated.

I created 3 menus (one for each language) with each time a home page (the flags appear in the menu)

I installed the multilanguage module it seems to be good.

Then I went to the template manager. Let a style for "all languages" and created copies for each language. For each language, I choose the good menu.

Is there anything wrong with what I did ?

I'm really welcoming any kind of help...

The URL is: www.bsports.be

(On safari, I've a too many redirect issue, not on chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settled thanks to:
http://forum.joomla.fr/showthread.php?165020-Erreur-The-requested-URL-was-not-found-on-this-server

Made some change to the .htaccess and it works fine now, hope this will help others